# sql database multiple DISTINCT reads

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a database that has several columns.

I am developing my own filter, so user can search the database. What i want to do is get the different entries from each column in the database.

`DISTINCT` works for one column. so sql syntax is `SELECT DISTINCT COLUMN FROM TABLE1`

what I'm doing atm is `SELECT DISTINCT COLUMN FROM TABLE1`,

than another read is `SELECT DISTINCT COLUMN1 FROM TABLE1`
than another read is `SELECT DISTINCT COLUMN2 FROM TABLE1`

etc

I was simply wondering if there was a better way. or a way i can combine these into same syntax

The design of the system is, page loads, it loads all the rows from the database and populates a tablelist. At the same time, it gets all the different entries from each column. This data is shown in drop downs, so data can't be edited it just to view it.

thanks

Comment: Why?  are you using these values to populate drop downs?  if so, what happens when a new value is added that doesn't exist in table1 yet?  it is possible to do what your asking depending on database and version syntax varies, but without understanding how it's going to be used, I don't want to send you down a bad design.

Comment: What is the master table for the values?  if table1 is a work table **you don't want to go there to get the list of values** for the drop downs.  If a new value is added to the master list, it will not appear on your drop down until the work table somehow gets an entry.  if your form is the new way to get values there, it will never show up!  Go to the authoritative source for the list, not an association.  It is for this reason that you may want to have multiple trips to the database for each listing.  Alternatively if all values are in the same table, return the sets subset outside of the db

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure you can do all that in one query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT MyColumn FROM MyTable
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT MyColumn2 FROM MyTable
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT MyColumn3 FROM MyTable
(etc.)
```

If you want duplicate values when a value occurs in multiple columns, use `UNION ALL`.

Answer (score 0):

You certainly can use distinct on multiple columns, but it may not be what you are looking for.

```
select distinct col1,col2 from MyTable
```

Where MyTable is:

```
|col1|col2|col3|
----------------
|   a|   b|   c|
|   a|   b|   d|
|   a|   c|   c|
|   b|   c|   f|
```

This will return results:

```
|col1|col2|
-----------
|   a|   b|
|   a|   c|
|   b|   c|
```

**Edit:** Since you are populating drop down lists you probably want to select one column at a time.

Comment: i do, ill read each column at a time, just didn't seem very efficient